# Java class compilation issue with jar dependency

Tags: java

I am compiling a java class say A which have some dependencies of the external jar
Now there is another class B - In class B there is an object of class A and some dependencies of the external jar

```
public class A{
      // external Jar dependency code
     } 

public class B{
       A a;
      // external Jar dependency code
     }
```

When I compile class A with

1. javac -cp [jar reference] A.java - Runs successfully
2. javac -cp [jar reference] B.java - Error (Cannot find symbol A)
3. When I remove the external jar reference code from class B and compile it using javac B.java - - Runs successfully

I don't know what is the issue here.

Comment: what was the "error"?

Comment: are A and B in the same package?

Comment: Do you import class A into class B? please provide your code, this way it's very difficult to suggest something.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Yes Both are in same package

Comment: @Joe The error is cannot find symbol A while compile class B

Comment: if they're in the same package, it should be able to find A. we'll need more details of the classes to see what's wrong. Can you boil it down to a simple example that you can include in the question? Just the minimum structure that gives you the error would be great.

Comment: import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

`@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class A{
    
}


import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class B {
    A a;
}`

Jar Reference - jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar

@AlwaysLearning

Comment: The commands I used to compile these files are

javac -cp .\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar .\A.java
javac -cp .\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar .\B.java

The error while compiling class B.java is

.\B.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    A a;
    ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class B
1 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Got the solution.

When passing reference of jars one have to pass the reference of other classes as well

e.g.

for my case

javac -cp .\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar .\A.java .\B.java